# What does 適 mean in this quote?

Tags: meaning, classical-japanese

I am unsure what 適 means in this (well-known?) quote:

> 人の適を適として、自ら其の適を適とせざる者なり

Based on Google search, it seems to mean something like 楽しみ but I cannot find the mention of this meaning in any dictionaries, including [this one](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E9%81%A9).

Comment: The quote seems to be the kundoku expansion of the following *Zhuangzi* quote: 「適人之適，而不自適其適者也」 "sought to secure for them what they desired, not seeking their own pleasure" (tr. James Legge).

Comment: You need a decent 漢和辞典 to look up a kanji's meaning used only in kanbun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my print edition of 角川漢和辞典, a number of entries are listed for 適.  Here is a sampling:

```
一
①ゆく（往）おもむく。いたる。
②よめにゆく。とつぐ。
③よつぎ。あとつぎ。

二
①かなう。気がその方に向く。気にいる。「自適」
②あてはまる。ほどよくかなう。「適当」
③たのしい。たのしむ。「快適」
```

It would seem the last of these corresponds to your sensed meaning of 適.